# Symfony2 + Doctrine - Get object with all the relationship data

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm

Maybe I'm asking a stupid question or maybe what I'm searching for doesn't exist. In this case it would be a nice feature. 
Is there a way to get one object with all the related entities and have all that data printed out is some way?

For example, I have a `Customer` entity and a `Location` entity. They are in a `ManyToOne` relationship (One Customer can have multiple Locations).

I want to return a `JsonResponse` with a structure like this one:

```
    { customer:
      [ {id: , name: , locations:
        [ {id: , name: , address: }
        ]}
      ]
    }
```

My idea is to call a method (if there is one) which returns an array that has the structure of the object with all the other related objects, and then to apply the `jms_serializer` to return the JSON structure.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I wrote the solutions as an answer.

Comment: So basically you just want to serialize a Customer object, should be rather straightforward using (JMS)Serializer.

Comment: @Gerry Thanks, I solved!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than I thought. Here it is, in case somebody needs it:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Customers');
    $customers = $repository->findAll();
    $i = count($customers);

    for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {

        $a['customers'][$j] = $customers[$j];

    }

    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $response = $serializer->serialize($a,'json');

    return new Response($response);
```